# Extract a string by webscraping using python

Tags: python, web-scraping

Below is a portion of an HTML file:

[image]

I want to webscrape the highlighted lines only. This is portion of a large fie. For this portion, I tried:

```
container5 = container1[1 ].findAll("strong")

container6 = (container5[6]).text
print(container6)
```

But the output was:

```
Address:
```

How do I extract the string containing the address inside the `" "` portion of the image?

Comment: Only the word "address:" is inside the `<strong>` tag, the actual address is inside another element. It looks like you need to be looking inside `<br>` tags instead

Comment: Do not post images of text, instead copy-and-paste the actual text directly into your post. Images of text are not easily parsable, searchable, or accessible.

Comment: @G.Anderson `<br>` tags are always empty. The HTML is sub-optimally structured for parsing this data. Will need instead to get the text node following a `<strong>`.

Answer (score 0):

I like to parse this sort of thing using the python `split()` function.  The thing to notice is the recurring pattern around the data.

```
...<strong>SOME-Field-Name:</strong> ...
"The desired value"
<br> ...
```

This pattern gives you a place of leverage where the code can work, and thus presents an approach for some code:

```
html = "... <strong>Address:</strong>\n\" 1100 Space Park etc.\"\n<br>\n ..."

# extract the Address field, between it's heading and </br>
field = html.split("Address:</strong>")[1].split("<")[0].strip()

# Trim away the quotes and whitespace
value = field.split("\"")[1].strip()
```

Outputs:

```
>>> value
'1100 Space Park etc.'
```

The [split function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) cuts the string up into a list, removing the part you split with.
So the first split gives `['... <strong>', '\n\" 1000 Space Park...' ]`, and we just take the 2nd item `[1]`.  We then re-split this with `<`, which gives everything before the `<br>` and some other stuff we don't care about, so the first element is a keeper `[0]`.

We cleanup some whitespace with `strip()`, then de-quote the result.

Using this approach, you can fetch the other values too.  Probably best in a function.

```
def getField(html, field_name):
    # TODO - add some error checking for when not found, etc.
    field = html.split(field_name+":</strong>")[1].split("<")[0].strip()
    value = field.split("\"")[1].strip()
    return value

address = getField(html, "Address")
size    = getField(html, "Gross SqFt")
power   = getField(html, "Total Power")
# etc.
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But there are thousands of other links of same format in the file that I am webscraping.  So I have to perform a for loop on the links. And, therefore, I don't think copying the HTML file is going to work in this case. Somehow, I have to find the tag that contains the text inside the string.